# How can I make a textbox only accept a valid email?

Tags: c#, winforms, email, visual-studio-2013, textbox

I would like my textbox to check if the email that is entered into the textbox is valid.

So far I have got:

```
if (!this.txtEmail.Text.Contains('@') || !this.txtEmail.Text.Contains('.')) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Please Enter A Valid Email", "Invalid Email", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error); 
}
```

But this only tests if it has a '@' and a '.' in it.

Is there a way to make it check to see if it has .com etc. and only one '@'?

Comment: Validating email addresses is difficult. The easiest way is to do, what you already did: look for `@` and `.`. If those are present, send an email to that address and let the user confirm its authenticity.

Comment: Check this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/jZ3jT5/1)

Comment: Most of the different UI (and web) frameworks in the C# space have validators, and usually also one specifically for validating email addresses.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.NET can do it for you:

```
  bool IsValidEmail(string eMail)
  {
     bool Result = false;

     try
     {
        var eMailValidator = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(eMail);

        Result = (eMail.LastIndexOf(".") > eMail.LastIndexOf("@"));
     }
     catch
     {
        Result = false;
     };

     return Result;
  }
```

Comment: If i use "test@test" this passes as a valid email address using this approach.

Comment: Although it is useful, it doesn't check for a correct email address format, like @DDuffy said, passing "test@test" results as a "valid" email.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [MailAddress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

```
    var email = new MailAddress("abc123@example.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing a web app, modern browsers support HTML5, so you can use `<input id="txtEmail" type="email" runat="server" />` instead of a TextBox and it will validate the input is an email in the browser (but you should also validate it in your code).  Use txtEmail.Value to get the text string.